# Create object from link does not implement parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to generate a link that creates a new object. It creates the object, but without setting the user_id or subreddit_id.

```
<%= link_to ' (add to my subreddits)', 
            { 
              controller: 'subscriptions',
              action: 'create',
              user_id: current_user.id,
              subreddit_id: subreddit.id
            },
              method: :post %>
```

here are the relevant controllers:

```
def new
@subscription = Subscription.new

unless current_user.admin?
  @subscription.user_id = current_user.id
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @subscription }
end
end

def create
@subscription = Subscription.new(params[:subscription])

unless current_user.admin?
  @subscription.user_id = current_user.id
end

respond_to do |format|
  if @subscription.save
    format.html { redirect_to @subscription, notice: 'Subscription was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @subscription, status: :created, location: @subscription }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @subscription.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Comment: Use this <%= link_to ' (add to my subreddits)', subscriptions_path({:user_id => :current_user.id, :subreddit_id => :subreddit.id), :action => :create, :method => :post %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your error is here:

```
# in create
@subscription = Subscription.new(params[:subscription])
```

You don't set the value for `subscription` parameter. You set `params[:user_id]` and `params[:subreddit_id]`. Use them on creating your Subscription, like:

```
@subscription = Subscription.new(
  user_id: params[:user_id], 
  subreddit_id: params[:subreddit_id]
)
```

Comment: thanks! I changed the link instead of the controller, but the same idea

Comment: <%= link_to ' (add to my subreddits)', 
                { 
                  controller: 'subscriptions',
                  action: 'create',
                  subscription: {
                    user_id: current_user.id,
                    subreddit_id: subreddit.id
                  }
                },
                  method: :post %>